# Is the MATCH worksheet function allowed in a named range for Excel charts?

Tags: excel, charts, named-ranges

The following two named range definitions are valid (verified by Excel), and both highlight the same range of cells.

```
=OFFSET('AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$C$1, COUNT('AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$C$2:$C$10000) - 29, 0, 30, 1)
```

and

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(TODAY(), 'AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$A$1:$A$10000, 0), MATCH("RAXMTR_1", 'AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$A$1:$ZZ$1, 0))), -29, 0, 30, 1)
```

The first named range is accepted as a chart series, and it plots the data just fine. The second named range (pointing to the same cells) is not accepted. Excel throws up an error window saying, "We found a problem with one or more formula references in this worksheet."

I've tried using a static date in place of the `TODAY` function, but it still didn't work. That shouldn't be the issue, though, since Excel will highlight the appropriate cells for both named ranges.

The only thing I can think of is that Excel charts cannot use named ranges that include the `MATCH` function. Is this true? If so, is there an alternative way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are truly *'both highlight the same range of cells'* then that is a peculiarity to your data. On two sets of sample data I got disparate results. It's not wise to rely on formulas that only work sometimes.

It seems that you want to chart the data in the column with RAXMTR_1 in the column header. In this case that is column C. You want a 30-day 'window' of data ending in TODAY().

Throwing out of all the volatile [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) and [ADDRESS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89) functions, this may be a better formula.

```
=INDEX('AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$A:$ZZ, MATCH(TODAY(), 'AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$A:$A, 0)-29, MATCH("RAXMTR_1",1:1, 0)):INDEX('AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$A:$ZZ, MATCH(TODAY(), 'AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$A:$A, 0), MATCH("RAXMTR_1",1:1, 0))
```

This does produce results identical to your second formula. There should be no issue using it as the *Refers to:* in a named range (assuming that you have sufficient data to allow a 30 day backstep).

Your question is decidedly short on details about your data. Using `MATCH(TODAY()-30, ...` might be a better formula than subtracting 29 from the row returned by matching TODAY but that would only work if the days were sequential.

fwiw, that formula remains volatile as the [TODAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566) is volatile as well.

Comment: On my data sets, both formulas gave the same results all the time. Just the second one produced an error while charting. You understood exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I tried your sample using the `INDEX` function, instead of the `INDIRECT`, `OFFSET`, and `ADDRESS` functions, and it seems to work fine. I think you're correct about the charts not allowing the more volatile functions. Unfortunately, there's no way I can avoid using `TODAY`. Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

For the second defined name try this:

```
=OFFSET('AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$A$1,MATCH(TODAY(), 'AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$A$1:$A$10000, 0)-1-29,MATCH("RAXMTR_1", 'AU_ARENDOFDAY Times'!$A$1:$ZZ$1, 0)-1, 30, 1)
```

Hope this helps. I was able to put that in a defined name an then plot the data. It may be INDIRECT that doesn't work in defined names.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I think you're right that the charts didn't like the `INDIRECT` function, because leaving the `MATCH` calls in there worked just fine.